# favicon is pixelated in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I have created a 16x16px favicon for a website, but I am getting complaints that IE pixelates it. should I have a larger size? is their a way to use multiple sizes? What is best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a 32x32 one, the other browsers will resize it on their own.

Comment: +1 with one small caveat: Google Chrome supports only 16x16 when the ICO format is used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: Didn't know that. Workaround: just use .png, as you should not use the implicit way (putting favicon.ico to webserver root) anyway.

Comment: @joni why not? that is exactly how I was told to do it.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz doing it explicitly is always better

Comment: yeah, I don't have a real argument as you see :P but I'm used to do it like this.

Comment: I do both, as I use wordpress. One in root, one in theme. Without the non-explicit root one, feed readers wouldn't get it

Comment: to clarify then, using a 32*32 px png will work for all but chrome?

Comment: no, using the 32x32 png is just for making it work for chrome. but then, on the other side, it will not work anymore for IE... http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/PNGSupportFavicon.html

Comment: You can dynamically add a link element to the favicon based on browser detection...

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what "IE pixelates it" means.

In most locations, IE shows FavIcons @ 16x16, so sending a 16x16 icon isn't going to break anything.

However, keep in mind that IE uses the ICO file type because it can hold multiple image sizes. You should consider sending both a 16x16 and a 32x32 icon in the same file, so that in the few contexts where larger icons are shown (e.g. desktop shortcut creation, pinned sites in Win7, etc) you have a nice high-resolution image available.